# How to access only dashboard tab to monitor graphs in kibana4 using Shield?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4, elasticsearch-plugin

How can i create a role for a user to access only dashboard tab to monitoring the graphs in kibana4 using shield?

The role must satisfy the below conditions

> -The role must not have access to Discover tab,Visualize Tab and Settings tab.
>             -The role must have access to dashboard tab only.

Is this possible in Kibana4 with shield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/kibana.html), it is not currently possible with Shield:

> Kibana and Shield do not currently provide a way to control which users can load which dashboards.

There is the [issue #4453](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/4453) that you might want to follow, if you're interested in how they will be solving this (and you can +1 it, too)

You can still protect your dashboard using either Apache or Nginx. See [this discussion](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-protect-kibana-4-dashboards-using-apache-httpd/28396/3) and [this one](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-4-dashboards-access-control-with-shield/2151/18).